# If $X$ is a non-negative r.v., and $E(X\mathbb{1}_{X>t}) \leq \frac{2}{t}$, show $E(X\mathbb{1}_{E}) \leq \sqrt{8P(E)}$ for any $E \in \mathcal{F}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, stochastic-processes

Suppose that $X$ is a non-negative r.v. on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathrm{P})$ where for $t>0$, it is true that $\mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{1}_{X>t}) \leq \frac{2}{t}$. I want to show that for any $E \in \mathcal{F}$, we have that:

$$
\mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{1}_{E}) \leq \sqrt{8\mathrm{P}(E)}
$$

Any idea that comes to mind is Markov's inequality. However, I am not sure how to manipulate what is given that my expectation on the left is bounded above by $\frac{2}{t}$. Could anyone give a hint? Thanks.

Comment: I am not following how $E$ enters or affects the left hand side of the inequality you need to prove. If $E\in\mathcal{F}$ is arbitrary, you only have that $P(E) \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Hi, sorry I made a mistake, I just fixed it,

Answer (score 3):

The given assumptions essentially scream at us to consider the splitting
$$
\Bbb{E} (X 1_E) = \Bbb{E}(X 1_{E \cap \{X \leq t\}}) + \Bbb{E}(X 1_{E \cap \{X > t\}}) \leq t \cdot \Bbb{P}(E) + \Bbb{E}(X 1_{X > t}) \leq t \cdot \Bbb{P}(E) + \frac{2}{t}.
$$

For $\Bbb{P}(E) = 0$, the claim is clear, so that we can assume $\Bbb{P}(E) > 0$. Now, optimize the bound from above w.r.t. $t$. Specifically, let $t = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\Bbb{P}(E)}}$. This implies
$$
\Bbb{E}(X 1_E) \leq \sqrt{2 \Bbb{P}(E)} + \sqrt{2 \Bbb{P}(E)} = \sqrt{8 \Bbb{P}(E)},
$$
as desired.

Comment: Could you explain how you went from $\Bbb{E}(X 1_{E \cap \{f \leq t\}}) + \Bbb{E}(X 1_{E \cap \{f > t\}})$ to  $t \cdot \Bbb{P}(E) + \Bbb{E}(X 1_{X > t})$ in the inequality you have?

Comment: Additionally, by $f \leq t$ do you mean $X \leq t$?

Comment: @user123276: Oh yeah, $f $ is $X $. I will edit. Also, on the set $E\cap \{X \leq t\{$, we have $X \leq t $. From this, we get $E (X 1_{...})\leq t P (E) $. For the second term, note $X \geq 0$, so that $E (X 1_{E \cap ...})\leq E (X 1_{...}) $.

Comment: Could I ask why the set $E \cap \{X \leq t\}$ results in $X \leq t$? I am thinking that this intuitively will occur if $\{X \leq t\}$ is a subset of $E$, but am not sure why, since $E$ appears to have been chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: @user123276: We are **intersecting** $E$ with the set $\{X \leq t\} =: F$. On $F$, we clearly have $X \leq t$. Thus, the same is also true on any subset of $F$. In particular on $E \cap \{X \leq t\} = E \cap F \subset F$.

Comment: So am I right in saying that $E \cap F \subset F$ but it also holds that $E \cap F \subset E$? But that we used the former because that helps us solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @user123276: Yes, exactly.